# Why is my WAR file automatically exploded in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, war

In Tomcat, I found the .war will be automatically exploded. Is this the behavior expected?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out `unpackWARs` option in `server.xml`:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

I guess working on exploded archive is faster (I have no idea whether Tomcat explodes the file in-memory when `unpackWARs` is `false` or uses some other technique).

Answer (score 3):

> Is this the behavior expected?

Yes.  This is the default behavior: see the [Context config documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) ... and search for unpackWARs.

You can change this on a per-webapp basis using the Context container or you can change it for all webapps using the Host container.